# CSS is not getting targeted based on the page zoom level?

Tags: javascript

I am wondering is there a way to modify a given CSS depending on the zoom level of the page? For example if the page zoom level, is zoomed above 100%(e.g 110%, 120% etc..) then I want to remove the following CSS:

```
.square{
 width: 190px;
 height: 190px;
 background: black;
}
```

If the zoom level is 100% or below, then I want to keep the CSS.

Is there a way to dynamically remove and add css depending on the page zoom level? In this case, I want to show the square shape, if the page zoom level is 100% or below. If the zoom level is above 100% then remove the square shape.

It looks like I can use the following calculation to determine the zoom size but how can I see use this to add or remove the CSS?

let zoom = (( window.outerWidth - 10 ) / window.innerWidth) * 100;

This is what I have attempted, but it's not working when I zoom my browser:

```
$(window).on('resize', function (e) {
        var zoom = ((window.outerWidth - 10) / window.innerWidth) * 100;
        if(zoom > 100){
            $(".square").addClass("zoomed");
        }       
    });
```

When I zoom my browser to 110%, I'd expect it to add the class `zoomed` to square, but it is not doing that. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Is the page zoom size calculation wrong? Or is it the JavaScript?

Comment: When i run your code, nothing happens. But if i use `$(window).on('resize'` then i can see something happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you are trying to add and remove the `zoomed` class based on the zoom level, you are missing the `removeClass` when zoom level is not above 100%. Or, you can simply use [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/). Also, the [resize event](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) is sent to `window` instead of `document`.

Note that there are [many methods to test the zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers) based on your browser, you might want to look into it.

```js
$(window).on("resize", function(e) {
  $(".square").toggleClass("zoomed", window.devicePixelRatio > 1);
});
```

```css
.square {
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  background: black;
}

.zoomed {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square"></div>
```